# How to take specific JSON data iteratively and display as HTML

Tags: javascript, json, loops, bing-api

I have looked through many similar posts on SO where users ask questions on how to display JSON data in the client side. What I have struggled with is that most examples are working with rather simple JSON data. I am using the Bing web search API and have successfully managed to call the API and receive the JSON response data.

Below Example Response:
Note this is just returning one result, there will be many results in the full response.

```
result = {
 "_type": "SearchResponse",
  "queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "Microsoft Cognitive Services"
  },
  "webPages": {
    "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=Microsoft+cognitive+services",
    "totalEstimatedMatches": 22300000,
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0",
        "name": "Microsoft Cognitive Services",
        "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
        "displayUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
        "snippet": "Knock down barriers between you and your ideas. Enable natural and contextual interaction with tools that augment users' experiences via the power of machine-based AI. Plug them in and bring your ideas to life.",
        "deepLinks": [
          {
            "name": "Face",
            "url": "https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cognitive-services/face/",
            "snippet": "Add facial recognition to your applications to detect, identify, and verify faces using a Face service from Microsoft Azure. ... Cognitive Services; Face service;"
          },
          {
            "name": "Text Analytics",
            "url": "https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/",
            "snippet": "Cognitive Services; Text Analytics API; Text Analytics API . Detect sentiment, ... you agree that Microsoft may store it and use it to improve Microsoft services, ..."
          },
          {
            "name": "Computer Vision API",
            "url": "https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/",
            "snippet": "Extract the data you need from images using optical character recognition and image analytics with Computer Vision APIs from Microsoft Azure."
          },
          {
            "name": "Emotion",
            "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/emotion-api",
            "snippet": "Cognitive Services Emotion API - microsoft.com"
          },
          {
            "name": "Bing Speech API",
            "url": "https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cognitive-services/speech/",
            "snippet": "Add speech recognition to your applications, including text to speech, with a speech API from Microsoft Azure. ... Cognitive Services; Bing Speech API;"
          },
          {
            "name": "Get Started for Free",
            "url": "https://azure.microsoft.com/services/cognitive-services/",
            "snippet": "Add vision, speech, language, and knowledge capabilities to your applications using intelligence APIs and SDKs from Cognitive Services."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "relatedSearches": {
    "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#RelatedSearches",
    "value": [
      {
        "text": "microsoft bot framework",
        "displayText": "microsoft bot framework",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+bot+framework"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services youtube",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services youtube",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+youtube"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services search api",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services search api",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+search+api"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services news",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services news",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+news"
      },
      {
        "text": "ms cognitive service",
        "displayText": "ms cognitive service",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=ms+cognitive+service"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services text analytics",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services text analytics",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+text+analytics"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services toolkit",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services toolkit",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+toolkit"
      },
      {
        "text": "microsoft cognitive services api",
        "displayText": "microsoft cognitive services api",
        "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=microsoft+cognitive+services+api"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rankingResponse": {
    "mainline": {
      "items": [
        {
          "answerType": "WebPages",
          "resultIndex": 0,
          "value": {
            "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "sidebar": {
      "items": [
        {
          "answerType": "RelatedSearches",
          "value": {
            "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#RelatedSearches"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to do next is to display specific elements from each value of the search results. Value is the array position of each search result.

ie `result.webPages.value[0].name`
= Microsoft Cognitive Services

I want to read the JSON data, extract the items: "name", "displayURL", "Snippet" from "Value" (where there are multiple and Value I think is an array)
Then display the extracts in my page.

What I am doing to show certain data in my page so far:

```
<html>
<!-- Ideally should be only one dive that has all the results-->
  <div id="result1"></div>
  <div id="result2"></div>
  <div id="result3"></div>
</html>

<script>
// ideally should be a for loop instead of writing same code again
   document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<a href='"+result.webPages.value[0].displayUrl+"'>"+result.webPages.value[0].name+"</a>" +"<br>" + result.webPages.value[0].snippet;
   document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = "<a href='"+result.webPages.value[1].displayUrl+"'>"+result.webPages.value[1].name+"</a>" +"<br>" + result.webPages.value[1].snippet;
   document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = "<a href='"+result.webPages.value[2].displayUrl+"'>"+result.webPages.value[2].name+"</a>" +"<br>" + result.webPages.value[2].snippet;
</script>
```

I know that I need to have a loop of some kind.
Loop through the JSON, grab each name, displayUrl, snippet from each Value[i].
Then append the values so you have something simmilar to what you see when you do a web search using the bing search or google search page.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
  var resultItemsName = resultItems[i].name;
  var resultItemsUrl = resultItems[i].displayUrl;
  var resultItemsDescription = resultItems[i].snippet;
  document.getElementById('display-results') // push the extracts to the div called display-results
}
```

I am not sure what I need to do as I require 3 items for each "Value"

Thank you in advance.

see my fiddle for current progress: It only has one result
https://jsfiddle.net/q9bxrgy7/2/

UPDATE: See my new fiddle that uses the search for 'dog'

https://jsfiddle.net/q9bxrgy7/3/

Comment: The json hasn't `result.webPages.value[1]`. so you have just `result.webPages.value[0]`

Comment: which `snippet` you mean inside `deepLinks`  i.e :`"snippet": "Add facia..`  ?

Comment: The actual response has many, I just included the first value for ease.

Comment: No, not inside the deeplinks. look at webpages.value, the items there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `result.webPages.value` in some variable and then use `for-loop` to loop through that datas then append your htmls in some variable using `+=` and then finally use `innerHTML` to assign this generated html in your div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var result = {
  "_type": "SearchResponse",
  "queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "Microsoft Cognitive Services"
  },
  "webPages": {
    "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=Microsoft+cognitive+services",
    "totalEstimatedMatches": 22300000,
    "value": [{
      "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0",
      "name": "Microsoft Cognitive Services",
      "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
      "displayUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
      "snippet": "Soemthings"

    }, {
      "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0",
      "name": "Microsoft Cognitive Services1",
      "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
      "displayUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services",
      "snippet": "Soemthings1"

    }]
  }
}


var results = result.webPages.value //get value array
var html = ""; //declare this
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var resultItemsName = results[i].name;
  var resultItemsUrl = results[i].displayUrl;
  var resultItemsDescription = results[i].snippet;
  html += "<div><a href='" + resultItemsUrl + "'>" + resultItemsName + "</a>" + "<br>" + resultItemsDescription + "</div>"; //append new rows 

}
document.getElementById('display-results').innerHTML = html //add htmls to divs
```

```html
<div id="display-results"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @swati, I added my updated fiddle for a more realistic example.